# Any ways to add new (edit) shortucts in OneNote 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I can't find a way to add a customized keyboard shortcut in OneNote 2010.

In particular, I want to change the default "ALT + =" shortcut, which adds a new equation.
(the key combination doesn't work with my layout!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.onenotehelp.com/2009/11/19/keyboard-shortcuts-for-onenote-2010/

> "Michael C. Oldenburg [MSFT]
>
> 9. Jan, 2010
>
> Hi Jonathan, keyboard shortcuts have
>   to be carefully implemented so they
>   don’t collide with existing shortucts
>   in other parts of the program (and in
>   other programs). For this reason,
>   they’re generally not
>   user-configurable. However, you can
>   make their commands more accessible by
>   customizing the Ribbon. If you haven’t
>   done this before, you can get an idea
>   about how to do this by looking at
>   these Office 2007 Help articles:
>
> http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA102277541033.aspx
>
> http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA012341051033.aspx
>
> Hope this helps!"

I know it isn't much help but it's somthing!

Comment: Thanks but i already knew it :)

Comment: Michael, sorry but the shortcuts weren't that carefully implemented, they DO COLIIDE, at least in my office 2010, Spanish version. Italics are CTRL K, the same as add hyperlink, so I cant use this last shortcut.